# Constant EBUSY issues on Windows

Tags: windows, node.js, gulp, gulp-watch

I have a very simple Gulpfile:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    prefix = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
    gsass = require('gulp-sass');
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    gulp.src('scss/*.scss')
        .pipe(gsass({
            unixNewlines: true,
            style: 'compact'
        }))
        .pipe(prefix('last 2 versions'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('.'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['sass'], function() {
    gulp.watch('scss/*.scss', ['sass']);
});
```

When the SCSS file is changed and the `sass` task runs, I occasionally (about 10% of the time) get the following error message on the console:

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: EBUSY, open 'C:\whatever\scss\main.scss'
```

The error in question happens during the call to `gulp.src`. Passing the `read: false` option into that function stops the error from happening (but, of course, prevents sass from working).

This error is a problem because the watch task stops running whenever the error is encountered. Neither `gulp-plumber` nor `.on('error', ...)` help with this problem.

Is there a way to work around this issue? I'm on Windows, if it's relevant.

**A few more relevant points:**

- Removing sass entirely doesn't fix the issue.
- Putting a try/catch around the contents of either task also doesn't work.
- I'm using Sublime Text 3 to edit the file. I think the problem is that `gulp.src` tries to read the file while Sublime is still writing to it (though I'm not entirely sure).

Comment: Not sure if it's going to help with this issue, but you should be returning the stream you create with `gulp.src` - i.e. `return gulp.src().pipe(gulp.dest());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'm not entirely sure about this because I don't run Windows, but here's some pointers:

- Like I mentioned in the comment, always `return` your streams from gulp tasks. That way gulp's task manager knows when the task finishes and can properly sequence your dependencies.
- If you are overwriting files that are being used by the system, it's not recommended. See this issue for a little more detail: https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/3017
- I'm not sure this will help either, but you could try writing your compiled CSS into a subdirectory, say `./dist/css` or something along those lines.
- It may be worth opening an issue (after trying the above points first!) on [vinyl-fs](https://github.com/wearefractal/vinyl-fs/issues) which is the module used for `gulp.src` etc.

Comment: Thanks for your help! The first three suggestions didn't work, unfortunately; I think I am going to follow your fourth one. I'll probably file a bug on gulp rather than vinyl-fs, however, since I suspect this may also be an issue with gulp.watch.

Comment: ==== > Try this first  <=======
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36566236/npm-install-error-code-ebusy-errono-4082/45757541#45757541

Answer (score 3):

There is a decent chance you have one of your files open in Microsoft Word.  Word locks up access to the file.
Completely exit MS Word and re-build.
Fixed the problem for me.  Hope it helps!

Comment: I don't think so. These are code files, not ones I would open in word.

Comment: Is it possible you right-clicked and opened it there accidentally?
Certainly, I know one doesn't intentionally edit code in Word. But human error is a thing.  Maybe it's not Word and just some other program that's locking up the file.  Possibly a second instance of localserver is running?